# Discord bot cannot find text channel name or channelid

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I appreciate anyone who is willing to look at this. I'm trying to have my bot be able to look at a website and take data from that website and post it to my discord channel. I will try to post pictures as well. my node.js is all up to date. token is set correctly.

The error that I am seeing:

[image: Error that I am Seeing]

My issue is that it seems that the bot cannot access a specific channel. The bot itself has full administration on the server for testing. I have also tried different channels as well

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    ]
});

const token = process.env.BOT_TOKEN;
let messagesHistory = []; 

const channelID = '11553938285183795999';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
    checkWebsite();
    setInterval(checkWebsite, 600000);
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    console.log(message.content);

    if (message.content === '!checkBankruptcies') {
        checkWebsite();
        message.channel.send('Checking website for updates...');
    }

    if (message.content === '!lastCheckBankruptcies') {
        const lastTenMessages = messagesHistory.slice(-10);
        message.channel.send('Last 10 Check Bankruptcies:\n' + lastTenMessages.join('\n'));
    }
});

async function checkWebsite() {
    console.log('Checking website...'); 

    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://stockanalysis.com/actions/bankruptcies/'); 
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
        const tableRows = $('table.svelte-1jtwn20 tr').toArray();

        tableRows.forEach((row) => {
            const columns = $(row).find('td').toArray(); 
            if (columns.length > 0) {
                const data1 = $(columns[0]).text().trim(); 
                const data2 = $(columns[1]).text().trim(); 
                // Add more data extractions as needed
                const message = `Data 1: ${data1}\nData 2: ${data2}`; 

                const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
                if (channel && channel.type === 'text') {
                    console.log('Sending message to channel:', message);
                    channel.send(message);
                    messagesHistory.push(message);
                } else {
                    console.error(`Text channel with ID ${channelID} not found.`);
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

client.login(token);
```

Ive tried removing the bot and re adding the bot to the server. Redo all privilege's, reset token and using text channel name like 'general' and channelid '12345678910'.

What I'm expecting is that the bot is able connect and read commands from the user and display data. basically where the error doesn't say **'Text channel name general not found.'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is at the conditional line in which you try to check whether the channel is a text channel or not.

`if (channel && channel.type === 'text') {`

As shown in the [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#channel-object-channel-types), channels don't have the types as you wrote them down. Instead of `'text'`, you should have written `0`, which is the equivalent of the guild text type you searched for. It shoud look like this:

`if (channel && channel.type === 0) {`

Here you can see how it shows an error:

[image]

Hope this answer works for you!

Comment: I see my mistake. In my head, I was wanting it search for text channel so I put text down.  but each time it never worked. I'm super thankful for your answer. You solved my issue. I wish to commend you XD

Comment: Yeahh at first it's hard to get how things work haha, glad it has worked :D